# useFocusEffect hook is invoked even screen is in background when update global state on the screen in foreground

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I am developing react-native project. This question is mainly about the [useFocusEffect](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/) hook behaviour in my project.

I have several screens. There is a share data & each screen can update the data. So, I decided to use `context` to host the data via `useState` hook. When one screen `setMyData(`), the up-to-date data is available to all screens.

My data context to host shared data via `useState` hook:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const MyDataContext = React.createContext();

export const MyDataProvider = ({children}) => {
   const [myData, setMyData] = useState([]);
   ...
   return (
    <MyDataContext.Provider
      value={{
        myData,
        setMyData,
      }}>
      {children}
    </MyDataContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default MyDataContext;
```

(My `App` component is wrapped by the `MyDataContext.Provider`, I just don't show that part here since it is not the point of my question)

In each of my screen components, I need to process my data **once** when the screen is on the foreground (**visible**), and update the global state with updated data. I use [useFocusEffect](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/) hook. Something like below:

```
import {useFocusEffect} from '@react-navigation/native';
import MyDataContext from '../context/MyDataContext';

const MyScreenOne = ({navigation})=> {

   const {myData, setMyData} = useContext(MyDataContext);
   
   useFocusEffect(() => {
     console.log('#################  Screen one is FOCUSED! ');
    
     const updatedData = processData([...myData]);
     // set my data
     setMyData(updatedData);
     return () => {
       console.log('Screen one was unfocused');
     };
   }, []);//empty array to force code in hook only run once

   return (<View>
             <MyButton onPress={()=> navigation.navigate("MyScreenTwo")}>
              ...
           </View>
          )
}
...
```

As you can see I have a button which navigates user to another screen. The other screen has the same structure of having that `useFocusEffect` hook in which it processes & updates data of global state.

When I run my app, the following happens to me:

1. At first `MyScreenOne` is launched. `useFocusEffect` is invoked, data is processed and updated and set to global state via the `setMyData()`
2. Since `setMyData()` is called in above step, the re-rendering happens, at this time, the `useFocusEffect` of `MyScreenOne` is not invoked again, which is good and expected.
3. Now I press the button which navigates to `MyScreenTwo`. Same process happens on `MyScreenTwo`: `useFocusEffect` is invoked, data is processed and updated and set to global state via the `setMyData()`. NOTICE: `MyScreenOne` is now not visible and in background stack/memory.
4. Since in above step the global state is updated by the second screen, re-rendering happens again to all screens in memory. This time surprisingly the `useFocusEffect` of `MyScreenOne` is invoked again, because of that the global state is updated again by the hook in `MyScreenOne` again, and re-rendering happens again to screens in memory.
5. As you can imaging , endless re-rendering happens now due to in above step the background screen `MyScreenOne`'s `useFocusEffect` is invoked surprisingly.

Isn't `useFocusEffect` supposed to be run only when screen is visible? Why the `useFocusEffect` hook of background screen is also invoked when re-rendering happens? How to achieve what I need to only run the process data & update data once on each screen when the screen is visible in the meantime the data can be shared by all screens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`useFocusEffect` doesn't take a dependency array. You need to pass `useCallback` as mentioned in the docs:

```js
useFocusEffect(
 React.useCallback(() => {
   // whatever
 }, [])
);
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/